# How to parse yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS format date in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
const time = '2016-11-16 00:00:00.000';
const date = new Date(time);
console.info(date);
```

It seems safari cannot parse yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS format date( it returns NaN ) while chrome works fine, how can I parse this?

Comment: For parsing dates moment.js is the best library.If you dont have any problem using thrid party libraries you can use it

Comment: If you look at the output of what chrome has done `2016-11-16T00:00:00.000Z`, you will see it's put a `T` in the space, and added a `Z` at the end,..  If Safari is been picky, maybe you could do the same.

Answer (score 4):

try using moment js for that.
look at: [moment.js parse with format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)
for example:

```
var mydate = moment("2016-11-16 00:00:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").toDate();
```

didn't test the format I put there as moment.js might use different strings to define it but you can see it all in the doc link I wrote above

Answer (score 4):

I'd use momentjs for working with dates in javascript. Easy example:

```js
var time = '2016-11-16 00:00:00.000';
var m = moment.utc(time, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS");
console.log(m)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If Safari is been picky about the DataTime format, you could maybe do some simple string replace & concatenation.

```js
const time = '2016-11-16 00:00:00.000';
const date = new Date(time.replace(' ','T') + 'Z');
console.info(date);
```